# Applying OpenGL Depth Test to Orbiting Spheres

Tags: c++, opengl, depth-buffer

I'm writing a gravitational n-body simulation in C++, which is animated using OpenGL and GLUT (this is a hobby project).  The animation works fine, for the most part, however I've had two major problems that I'm unable to resolve:

- Although depth testing is enabled, it isn't working as expected, and
- The surfaces are ... well, messy.

My question is, how do I fix these problems?

Both problems can be seen in the following images (apologies for the links but I've not enough rep for image posting).  These are snapshots from a simulation of a simple orbit, viewed edge on.

[Here](http://s25.postimg.org/w4m2lj2f3/yellow_front.png) the yellow sphere is drawn in front of the purple one, as it should be.

[After half an orbit](http://s25.postimg.org/h9xh7csu7/yellow_behind.png) the yellow sphere is still drawn in front, even though it is further away.

The code used to create the animation is given below.

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include "Cluster.h" // My own class.

// Scale for animation.  Each unit in the animation = 1/SCALE m.
const double SCALE = 1e-10;
// Size of spheres for animation.
const double SPHERE_SIZE = 2e10*SCALE;

// Cluster object contains bodies and updates their positions.
Cluster cluster();

// Array of rgb colors for spheres.
GLfloat colorArr[4][4] =
{ 
   {0.7, 0.7, 0.0, 1.0},
   {0.73, 0.24, 0.95, 1.0},
}

void display()
{
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluLookAt( 0.0*SCALE, 5e11*SCALE, 0.0*SCALE  // eye is on y-axis outside orbit.
            , 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 
            , 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ); 

   for (int i=0; i<N; i++) // N is the number of bodies in cluster.
   { 
      glPushMatrix(); 
      glTranslated( SCALE*cluster.getX(i)     // Get coordinate of ith body.
                  , SCALE*cluster.getY(i)
                  , SCALE*cluster.getZ(i) );
      glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, colorArr[i]);
      glutSolidSphere(SPHERE_SIZE, 50, 50);
      glCullFace(GL_BACK);
      glPopMatrix();
   } 

   glutSwapBuffers();
} 

void reshape(GLint w, GLint h) 
{ 
   glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluPerspective(30.0, (GLfloat)w/(GLfloat)h, SCALE, 5e11*SCALE);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
} 

void animate() 
{ 
   // Update positions and redraw.
   cluster.update();
   display();
} 

void init() 
{ 
   GLfloat black[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
   GLfloat white[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5};
   GLfloat direction[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0};

   glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, white);
   glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 10);

   glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, black);
   glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, white);
   glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, white);
   glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, direction);

   glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
   glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
} 

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
   glutInit(&argc, argv);
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
   glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
   glutCreateWindow("Test Orbit");
   glutDisplayFunc(display);
   glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
   glutIdleFunc(animate);
   init();
   glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: See my answer about depth fighting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25580397/opengl-java-rendering-issue-polygons-flickering-and-disappearing/25588811#25588811.

Comment: Thanks, an excellent answer that cleared up a few things for me.  However, I've already included scaling in my code to avoid depth fighting; the spheres have a radius of 2.0, the camera is positioned at y=50, and the near and far clipping planes are 1e-10 and 50.0. As I write this I realise that the far/near ratio is way too high! I will fix it and get back to you.

Comment: I reduced the clipping plane far/near ratio to < 100 and it fixed both problems. Thank you!! 

I spent several hours searching for an similar question before posting my own but had not found yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL's depth buffer has limited precision, and the numbers you're using are large enough that you may be running into that precision limit.  You may want to read [this article about depth-buffer optimization](http://outerra.blogspot.com/2012/11/maximizing-depth-buffer-range-and.html), or simply use a larger unit than meters for representing astronomical distances.

Comment: Yes, precision was the problem; I had scaled down all distances prior to animation, however I had also scaled my near clipping plane making it tiny.  This caused my far/near ration to remain too large causing depth fighting. Thanks for your answer.